# How to view the class files of QuantumGIS for further development?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, development

I have been searching class files of QGIS for a while for customisation and edit it for a project..But I am unable to get or download the files...can anybody give some references if we can really view the files or its not availabe..
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this page, for how to get the source code

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#71-Source-Code

Here is a page on how to build QGIS

http://www.qgis.org/api/INSTALL.html

You can get the source code using the following git command:

```
git clone git://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS.git
```

Comment: thanks..but I want to compile my edited version of QGIS code on windows with visual studio 10...is it possible to setup development environment on windows?

Comment: yes it is definitely possible, just a little bit difficult. See the link http://www.qgis.org/api/INSTALL.html#toc13 & modify the reference to Visual studio 2008 to your visual studio. You just need to remember that Visual studio should have reference to all the other dependencies, and the easiest way, is to run it from the OSgeo command prompt, like they have mentioned in this article